# How to parse JSON string into ArrayList using Java?

Tags: java

I am getting following response from an API

```
String response={"balance":1000,
  "lastliability":2000,"profitarray":[[1,2,3],[67,88,99]],"previous":[99,88]}
```

I am trying to convert profitarray to ArrayList in Java like

```
    JSONObject res=new JSONObject(response);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temp=res.getString("profitarray")//something like this
ArrayList<Integer>yy=res.getString("previous");
```

Obviously, the outputs of res.getstring will be String and I want to convert them to ArrayList, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using and doesn't it already have a way to return Lists/Arrays?

Comment: Are you asking how to get `profitarray":[[1,2,3],[67,88,99]]` from the response ?  How to get `[[1,2,3],[67,88,99]]` from the response ? or how to convert  this `[[1,2,3],[67,88,99]]` from a String to arraylist  of Integers ?

Comment: @c0der i amalready getting them from response ,I want to convert them to respective arraylist so as to save them in database

Comment: @vlaz JSon simple

Comment: I want to convert the string response in arraylist ,the response is stringified array right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is to create **a Java class that model your response**. See this example using [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

*Response class:*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Response {
//    int balance;
//    int lastLiability;
//    ArrayList<Integer> previous;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> profitarray;
}
```

*Gson example:*

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"balance\":1000,\"lastliability\":2000,\"profitarray\":[[1,2,3],[67,88,99]],\"previous\":[99,88]}";

        Response response = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);
        System.out.println(response.profitarray);
    }
}
```

I guess that you should add accessors, equals/hashCode and all that noise — but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a complex way to do it, but since you wanted an ArrayList>, here we are

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response = "{\"balance\":1000,\n" +
            "  \"lastliability\":2000,\"profitarray\":[[1,2,3],[67,88,99]],\"previous\":[99,88]}";
    JSONObject res=new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray array = res.getJSONArray("profitarray");
    ArrayList<JSONArray> profitList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        profitList.add(array.getJSONArray(i));
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < profitList.size(); i++){
        JSONArray array1 = profitList.get(i);
        list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++){
            list1.add(array1.getInt(j));
        }
        finalList.add(list1);
    }
}
```

The ArrayList finalList contains the final output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JsonArray** to extract an array out of a JSON response. Later on, you can use Collections API to convert that array into an ArrayList.

```
    JsonObject res = new JsonObject(response);
    JsonArray array1 = res.getJsonArray("profitarray");
    JsonArray array2 = res.getJsonArray("previous");

    ArrayList<JsonObject> arrayList1 = new ArrayList(array1.length());
    ArrayList<JsonObject> arrayList2 = new ArrayList(array2.length());

    for(int i=0;i < array1.length();i++){
    arrayList1.add(array1.getJsonObject(i));
}
    for(int j=0;j < array2.length();j++){
    arrayList2.add(array2.getJsonObject(j));
}
```

Comment: Is there a documentation for that? All I can find is [this](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/target/apidocs/index.html) but it seems like the API is different - it's using `JsonObject` instead of `JSONObject` (different capitalisation). This is version 3, so perhaps it changed - I find some references to code using `JSONObject` but it seems to be for an earlier version [some version 1 project](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) points at [a dead documentation source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I have modified my answer for the same. By the by I had referred this: [https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html]

Comment: It dint work,I need ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> :(

Comment: array1 would not have worked but array2 would surely do. Isn't it?